# How would you explain inference conditional on cross-sectional fixed effects to a layman?

Tags: inference, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, intuition

The goal is to infer $\partial y / \partial x$, $x \in \mathbf{X}$.  You observe individuals $i$ over time $t$.

The model is
$$
y_{it} = \mathbf{X}_{it}\beta + \epsilon_{it}
$$

You can rewrite
$$
\epsilon_{it}  = \alpha_i + u_{it}
$$

and then subtract-off individual-level means

$$
y_{it} - \bar{y}_i = (\mathbf{X}_{it} - \bar{\mathbf{X}}_i)\beta + u_{it} -\bar{u}_i
$$
or simplified as
$$
y_{it}^W = \mathbf{X}_{it}^W\beta + u_{it}^W
$$

where $W$ denotes the "within" transformation (it uses only variation within $i$).

You're getting rid of $\alpha_i$, so the only thing left in the error term is stuff that varies with time.

**HOW WOULD YOU EXPLAIN THIS TO SOMEONE WHO KNOWS NOTHING ABOUT STATISTICS AND ISN'T GOING TO LOOK AT MATH?**

Say you want to explain how much weather influences ice cream sales in different cities.  But weather is correlated with lactose intolerance, say, and you don't have data on lactose intolerance rates.  You just know that it's different.  How do you explain to someone that you controlled for that by using fixed effects?

Comment: Take a look at the FE DAG and animation at https://nickchk.com/causalgraphs.html. I usually do a two-group version of that.